# how can I know the current classLoader in java

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I am learning the process of loading java class and encounter some confusion.

I know when loading a *java class*, **current classLoader** wont load the *java class* directly and it will delegate  to its *parent classLoader*(a recursive process) until it parent cant load this class.

---

*The question is* that ：**what is the current classLoader?** *Bootstrap? Extension? App?* 
how to get the current classLoader?. 
and I know there is an API:

```
xxx.Class.getClassLoader();
```

but I am not sure whether the *return value* is *currentClassLoader*. I think it should be the classLoader which load this *java class* in reality.

To describe my question more detail I will give an example. 
I get the follow content in a blog.

> *ThreadContextClassLoader* is used to deal with *java SPI*, Interface is defined in java `core lib` and loaded by *Bootstrap ClassLoader* and third party implement these interface then the jar are loaded by *AppClassLoader*
>   **Solution:** traditional classLoader cant deal with this case,because it cant discovery the third party jar when we use the third party implement in core lib.

most of the above that I can understand but the solution make me confusion:
for example, the Interface *CoreA* and class *CoreB* are in java `core lib` and should be loaded by *Bootstrap ClassLoader* and the *AImpl* is a implement of *A* by third party and should be loaded by *AppClass loader*.

the code segment as below:

```
 public Interface CoreA{
     void add();
 }

 public Interface AImpl implements CoreA{
     void add(){};
 }

 public class B{
      public void demo(){
         a = new AImpl();
      }
 }
```

then if we reference `B` in `main method`, then we will load `B` because the *class loader* of `B` is *Bootstrap* then about `AImpl` the current Loader is *Bootstrap* so it cant be found?
I dont know whether it is as what I guess?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Different environments use different class loading strategies. The default is to first propagate the class loading request to the parent class loader. If it is unable to load the class, this class loader will try to load it. However, some application server class loaders will not ask their parent class loader first, if they are able to load the class by themselves. Next, there is even more complex class loader magic in OSGi to implement a module system.

Comment: There is no such thing as a “current ClassLoader.”  Every class is loaded by a particular ClassLoader.  That’s all there is to it.

Comment: Sometimes I'm facing with term `current classloader` and it's fine, it's just a `classloader` of currently executed class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the 'current classloader' is the *real classloader*(load this class in reality) of class that refer it.

e.g.
if the *classLoader* of `class A` is *ext classloader* and `class A` refer class `B C D`. Then the 'current classloader' of `B C D` is *ext classLoader*. And of course the 'current classLoader' of *main class* is *System classLoader*.

Answer (score 11):

Generally speaking you are right, it can't be found. Let me show you the following example. Let's say we have 3 classes: `A`, `B` and `Main` like these:

```
public class A {
    public String a() {
        return "a";
    }
}

public class B {
    public String b() {
        return new A().a();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(new B().b());
    }
}
```

And we package these classes into correspondent jars: `a.jar`, `b.jar` and place `Main.class` into the working directory. After that let's test the following scenarios:

1) Everything (`A.class`, `B.class`, `Main.class`) is loaded by `system classloader` and works fine:

```
$ java -cp .:a.jar:b.jar Main
a
```

2) `B.class` is loaded by `system classloader` and `A.class` is loaded by `bootstrap classloader` and everything still works fine because `system classloader` delegates loading to `bootstrap classloader` (just because `bootstrap classloader` can load it):

```
$ java -Xbootclasspath/a:a.jar -cp .:b.jar Main
a
```

3) `A.class` is loaded by `system classloader` and `B.class` is loaded by `bootstrap classloader` (your case). In this scenario during loading of `B.class` current classloader is `bootstrap classloader`, but it can't found `B.class` and fails:

```
$ java -Xbootclasspath/a:b.jar -cp .:a.jar Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: A
        at B.b(B.java:4)
        at Main.main(Main.java:4)
```

Lets take a look at the last example more carefully. What's happening here:

1. Try to find class with `public static main(String[] args)` method

   1.1. `system classloader` hasn't loaded it yet so delegates to `extension classloader`

   1.2. `extension classloader` hasn't loaded it yet so delegates to `bootstrap classloader`

   1.3. `bootstrap classloader` hasn't loaded it yet and tries to load, it can't load it and returns control to `extension classloader`

   1.4. `extension classloader` tries to load, it can't load it and returns control to `system classloader`

   1.5. `system classloader` loads `Main.class`
2. `Main.class` is processed and we try to load `B.class` with current classloader `system classloader`

   2.1. `system classloader` hasn't loaded it yet so delegates to `extension classloader`

   2.2. `extension classloader` hasn't loaded it yet so delegates to `bootstrap classloader`

   2.3. `bootstrap classloader` hasn't loaded it yet and loads `B.class`
3. `B.class` is processed and and we try to load `A.class` with current classloader `bootstrap classloader`

   3.1. `bootstrap classloader` hasn't loaded it yet and tries to load and
   fails

I hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for your contribution. It does a great help for me. But I think there exist a small flaw in **section 2**                                           `because system classloader delegates loading to bootstrap classloader if can't load class itself`.  _system classloader_ delegates loading to _its parent classLoader_ is not beacuse it cant load class itself. Only if its _parent classloader_ cant deal with loading the java class then _current class_ will try to load class itself.

Comment: This answer should have more upvotes.  Extremely helpful.

Comment: follow up question:
This implies that if I am within a class loaded with `bootstrap classloader` , then I can only find and load other classes within core java. 

However, the implementations for classes like `ArrayList` (which to my understanding is loaded by `bootstrap classloader`) includes _generics_.

Answer (score 3):

When a class A attempts to load another class B, the ClassLoader that loaded A is the current ClassLoader. The word current vaguely refers to the execution context - e.g. how do you end up in the method that triggers the current class loading call.

There is no method - say `getCurrentClassLoader` - that simply gives the current ClassLoader, but there are api methods that internally use the concept of current ClassLoader. For example, `Class.forName(String className)`

If you check how that method is implemented, it tells you the meaning of "current class loader":

```
public static Class<?> forName(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class<?> caller = Reflection.getCallerClass();
    return forName0(className, true, ClassLoader.getClassLoader(caller), caller);
}
```

If you can get hold of a Class instance, you can always ask for the loader behind it by calling `Class::getClassLoader()` method. That will be your current class loader. The tricky bit, however, is to decide if the loader is bootstrap, or extension, or system class loader. The reason of the trickiness is that it is implementation specific, and you can always implement your own class loading mechanism.

The example given by @dmitrievanthony is an example of how things can become really complicated. It is a similar situation faced by JNDI, and the reason why the hack `Thread.getContextClassLoader()` was introduced. More about it [here](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077344/core-java/find-a-way-out-of-the-classloader-maze.html)

Quote the most relevant piece from the article:

> ... By definition, a current classloader loads and defines the class to which your current method belongs. This classloader is implied when dynamic links between classes resolve at runtime, and when you use the one-argument version of Class.forName(), Class.getResource(), and similar methods. It is also used by syntactic constructs like X.class class literals ...